# Intent изменяет uri

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

Для проигрывания видео запускается новая активити. Интенту скармливаю:

> http://login:password@media3.krasview.ru/video/96c0c47e08cf085/0a4886a064812c3.mp4

а его getDataString() возвращает

> http://login:password@media3.krasview.ru:-1/video/96c0c47e08cf085/0a4886a064812c3.mp4,

этот адрес проигрываться не хочет. Как исправить uri обратно?

Comment: Покажите, как в Intent помещаете значение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина в следующем. В Intent'е data хранится как Uri. А при парсинге строки в Uri вместо отсутствующего номера порта ставится -1.

> public abstract int getPort ()
>
> Gets the port from the authority for this URI. For example, if the authority is "google.com:80", this method will return 80.
>
> Returns
>
> the port for this URI or -1 if invalid or not present

Answer (score 3):

Как поместить значение в Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(имя вашего класса);
intent.putExtra(передаваемые данные, obj);
startIntent(intent);
```

---

Как принять данные:

getIntent().getExtra("принимаемые данные");

---

Uri не надо исправлять. 
<br>
"-1" в вашем изменённом uri - это код ошибки плеера.
<br>
перед `имяВашегоПлеера.play();`
<br>
впишите:
<br>
    имяВашегоПлеера.reset();
    <br>
    имяВашегоПлеера.prepare();

Comment: Спасибо. Проблему так и решила, задвинула адрес в экстры. Но, понятно, это будет работать только для самописных активити или для тех, где учтен такой вариант, просто отправлять ACTION_VIEW в свободное плавание не получится.